# list directories and subFolder of project

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to list directories and subdirectories I created in my application for instance :

```
-Assets
------Config
------BUILD
------------file.json
------------file2.json
------RUN
------------file3.json
```

ect

I can't find any method to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of searching I found this solution:

```
NSURL *myDirectoryURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Assets" withExtension:@""];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:myDirectoryURL includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray array] options:0 errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    // handle error
    return NO;
}];

NSString *fileOrDirectory = nil;
while ((fileOrDirectory = [directoryEnumerator nextObject])) {
    // use file or directory
    NSLog(@"%@", fileOrDirectory);
}
```